# Проверка значений поля на уникальность

Tags: activerecord, yii

Доброго времени суток!

Есть таблица с индексом уникальности сразу по двум полям:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name(
    id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    id_field INT(11) NOT NULL,
    title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    INDEX id_field (id_field),
    UNIQUE INDEX title (title, id_field) -- индекс
);
```

Как в `CActiveRecord::rules()` для поля `title` создать правило `unique` чтобы уникальность проверялась на по всей таблица, а, именно, в рамках значения `id_field`?

**UPD:** Рабочий код

```
// Controller

public function actionAction( $id_field,$id_item=null )
{
    // ...
    $item=null;
    if( $id_item!==null )
        $item=FieldItem::model()->findByPk($id_item);
    if( $item===null )
        $item=new FieldItem();

    if( isset($_POST['FieldItem']) )
    {
        $item->attributes=$_POST['FieldItem'];
        $item->id_field=$id_field;
        if( $item->save() )
            $this->redirect(/*...*/);
    }
    // ...
}

// FieldItem

public function rules()
{
    return array(
        //...
        array('title', 'uniqueTitle'),
        //...
    );
}

public function uniqueTitle( $attribute,$params=array() )
{
    if( !$this->hasErrors() )
    {
        $params['criteria']=array(
            'condition'=>'id_field=:id_field',
            'params'=>array(':id_field'=>$this->id_field),
        );
        $validator=CValidator::createValidator('unique',$this,$attribute,$params);
        $validator->validate($this,array($attribute));
    }
}
```

Comment: несовсем понял, вам нужно чтоб в таблице не повторялся title при равных равных значениях поял id_field?

Comment: Проверяться должна уникальность комбинации `id_field` и `title`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как я вас понял, поле title не должно повторятся при одинаковых значениях поля `id_field`. Если я правильно понял, попробуйте так, должно сработать (я давно такое делал), исходников нет под рукой, если не заработает, поправим.

В модели

```
public function rules() 
{
    array   (
        // невозможно создать элемент справочника с уже существующем именем
        array ( 'title', 
                'uniqueIdFieldAndTitleonAdd',
                'on'=>'add',
                'message'=>'запись с таким наименованием уже существует',
                ),
        //невозможно переименовать элемент в уже существующий
        array ( 'title', 
                'uniqueIdFieldAndTitleonEdit',
                'on'=>'edit',
                'message'=>'запись с таким наименованием уже существует',
                )
            )
    );
}

public function uniqueIdFieldAndTitleonAdd($attribute,$params=array())
{
    if(!$this->hasErrors())
    {
        $params['criteria']=array(
            'condition'=>'id_field=:id_field',
            'params'=>array(':id_field'=>$this->id_field),
        );
        $validator=CValidator::createValidator('unique',$this,$attribute,$params);
        $validator->validate($this,array($attribute));
    }
}

public function uniqueIdFieldAndTitleonEdit($attribute,$params=array())
{
    if(!$this->hasErrors())
    {
        $params['criteria']=array(
            'condition'=>'id_field!=:id_field',
            'params'=>array(':id_field'=>$this->id_field),
        );
        $validator=CValidator::createValidator('unique',$this,$attribute,$params);
        $validator->validate($this,array($attribute));
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. Получается, что решается только через кастомный валидатор?

2. Не понял, зачем разные валидаторы для `add` и `edit`?
И в чем смысл `id_field!=:id_field`?

Comment: add - сценарий добавления, то есть нельзя создать запись в базе если вней уже присутствует то же самое сочетание id_field и title.

edit - редактирование записи. Представь что ты отредактировал все но сочетание id_field и title не изменил, то предыдущий валидатор, составленный только для add тебя не пропустит

Comment: Посмотрел исходник [CUniqueValidator](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.12/framework/validators/CUniqueValidator.php#L110). Оказалось что там есть проверка на то, когда добавляется новая запись и когда меняется существующая. Поэтому первый валидатор пропустит изменение.

Но в целом понятно, спасибо.

Comment: Хм... Попробуйте, у меня измения не пропустил(

Comment: Я проверил перед тем как комментить. У меня все работает с одним валидатором. Тестил на 1.1.12. Хотя, судя по гитхабу, последние существенные изменения в этом классе делались очень давно.

Comment: ваще интересно стало. А код изменения записи можно привести?- уже спортивный интерес))

Comment: Без проблем. Добавил в топик.

Comment: я по другому делал изменение, поэтому походу и не срабатывало) попытаюсь завтра исходник найти - глянуть