# Почему валидация выполняется, хотя должна выдавать ошибку?

Tags: yii

Собственно ситуация такая:

Есть некоторая модель, в которой прописано следующее (делал по примеру):

```
public function rules()
{
    return array(
        array('begin_at', 'uniqueBeginAndEnd', 'message'=>'Сроки проведения с такими условиями уже заданы'),
    );
}

public function uniqueBeginAndEnd($attribute,$params=array())
{
    if(!$this->hasErrors())
    {
        $params['criteria']=array(
            'condition'=>'courses_id=:courses_id AND end_at=:end_at',
            'params'=>array(':courses_id'=>(int)$_GET['id'], ':end_at'=>$this->end_at),
        );
        $validator=CValidator::createValidator('unique',$this,$attribute,$params);
        $validator->validate($this,array($attribute));
    }
}
```

Т.е. если я буду пытаться создать новую или редактировать уже существующую запись, а запись с такими датами уже есть в таблице, то мне выдастся сообщение 'Сроки проведения с такими условиями уже заданы'. 
Так вот в чем проблема: на добавление новой записи валидация работает, а на редактирование нет (т.е. update проходит в любом случае).

Что добавление, что редактbрование делается стандартным $model->save()

P.S. Заранее извиняюсь, если объяснил не совсем внятно.

Comment: Добавьте в sql игнорирование текущий записи и все

Answer (score 2):

я бы сделал что-то типа этого.

```
public function rules()
{
    return array(
        array(
            'courses_id, end_at',
            'unique',
            'className' => 'название модели через которую ищем значение',
            'attributes' => array('первовый атрибут', 'второй атрибут'),
            'message' => 'Сроки проведения с такими условиями уже заданы'),
        array('courses_id, end_at', 'required'),
        array('courses_id, end_at', 'numerical'),
    );
}
```

**UPDATE**
И в таком случае стоит проверять что было передано от юзера, для этого нужны последние два правила.
Я предположил что end_at это число. Если это дата то нужен валидатор [date](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDateValidator)

**UPDATE 2**
С учётом вашего комментария:
На хеш-коде уже есть [похожий вопрос с принятым ответом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/138914/yii-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C)  (легко ищется через яндекс по запросу "yii проверить уникальность")
Коротко: вам нужно указать в правиле

```
'on'=>'add' //сработает при выполнении сценария добавления записи
'on'=>'edit' //при изменении записи
```

Comment: Если делать так, то courses_id и end_at будут проверять на уникальность по отдельности. А мне надо чтобы их сочетание было уникальным

Comment: Так я именно по этому примеру и делал))) и вот возник такой глюк

Comment: Короче не знаю куда написать, но кому то может пригодится. На собственные вопросы отвечать пока не могу. Нашел самое простое на мой взгляд решение (много не думать) http://yiihaa.com/validate-unique-constraints-with-more-then-one-attribute . Работает все супер. Только в параметре 'with'=>'атрибу1,атрибут2,...' указывайте все без пробелов

Answer (score 2):

Я делаю немного по другому валидацию, отличную от стандартных. Вот пример валидации имени товара:

```
public function rules()
{
    return array(
        array('name', 'filter', 'filter' => 'strip_tags'),
        array('name', 'filter', 'filter' => 'trim'),
        array('name', 'validItemName')
    );
}

public function validItemName($attribute,$params=array())
{
    $pattern = "/[\!\?\"\'\+\_\/\|]/";
    preg_match($pattern, $this->name, $matches);
    if($matches){
        $this->addError('name', 'Недопустимый символ '.$matches[0]);
    }
}
```

Возможно и Вам следует добавлять самостоятельно ошибку через $this->addError()